# Construct PHP strings to time from XML

Tags: php, xml, string, time

I'm trying to convert the following XML into a Time:

```
 <time hour="18" minute="05" timezone="Eastern" utc-hour="-4" utc-minute="00" />
```

I'm parsing the XML using SimpleXML, and storing that in a class.  I also tried printing out the following:

```
print strtotime($x->time->attributes()->hour . ":" . $x->time->attributes()->minute) . "<br>\n";
```

The results I got from that print looked something like this:

```
1249254300
```

I guess the result I'm expecting would be either **18:05** or **6:05 PM**

Is there any way I can get it to convert to the style I'm expecting?  Also, if I were to add the timezone onto the end is there any way for it to figure that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against using strtotime here.  Instead try [mktime](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_mktime.asp).

```
$time=mktime($x->time->attributes()->hour,$x->time->attributes()->minute,0,0,0,0)
```

Also you need to format the time stamp (what you printed out was the unix representation).  You can do this with the [date](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp) function.

```
date("H:i", $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bring it into a form [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) understands (including the timezone info)

```
<?php
$x = new SimpleXMLElement('<x>
    <time hour="18" minute="05" timezone="Eastern" utc-hour="-4" utc-minute="00" />
</x>');

$ts = sprintf('%02d:%02d %+03d%02d', $x->time['hour'], $x->time['minute'], $x->time['utc-hour'], $x->time['utc-minute']);
$ts = strtotime($ts);
echo gmdate(DateTime::RFC1123, $ts), "\n", date(DateTime::RFC1123, $ts);
```

My local timezone is CET/CEST (utc+2 in this case), therefore the script prints

```
Mon, 03 Aug 2009 22:05:00 +0000
Tue, 04 Aug 2009 00:05:00 +0200
```

Answer (score 1):

The `strToTime` function will recognize a date or time in string format, and then convert it to a Unix Timestamp (the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (the Unix epoch being January 1, 1970 a midnight, UTC).

So, what you need to do is take the resul of your `strToTime function, and use the date function to format them in a more human readable way`

```
//24 hour clock
print date(
      'H:i',
      strtotime($x->time->attributes()->hour . ":" . $x->time->attributes()->minute) . "<br>\n");

//12 hour clock
print date(
      'h:i a',
      strtotime($x->time->attributes()->hour . ":" . $x->time->attributes()->minute) . "<br>\n");
```

Full formatting options can be found [the date entry on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)